# Why should I use Model Binding instead of JSON deserializtion in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I am preparing an API where the client can pass some IDs via Http GET.

I have tried 2 different approaches

- Parameter Binding (Model Binding)
- JSON Deserialization

Both seem to work, but for this *easy* task like reading a list of IDs from the GET method, it seems much easier to just deserialize a list of IDs instead of creating an *IModelBinder* implementation.

**Example**

Call:

/api/favorites?IDs=[1337,1338]

WebAPI:

```
public class FavoritesController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public IHttpActionResult Get(string IDs)
   {
      var idList = Serializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(IDs)
      /* do some stuff */
      return Ok(someInfo);
   }
}
```

**Question**

To implement this with a ModelBinder it needs much more effort.
Reading on website from [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) or [Strathweb](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/), I just get the feeling that Model Binding is the way to go.
But what are the **advantages of using ModelBinders?**

Comment: The main advantages i find is that most stuff just works out of the box without having to write custom model binders. e.g. making a POST with json `[1,2,3,5]` would just automatically bind to an `IEnumerable<int>` parameter.

Comment: I agree regarding simple objects as Get parameter and also doing this example with a POST. But for this example, using non custom model binders, the call would be: /api/favorites?IDs=1337&IDs=1338, then it works like this: Get([FromUri] int[] IDs) But this is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Yes in this specific example, for a single instance it is easier to just pass a string and deserialise it in the controller, but if you had a custom model binder it is reusable.